# Find what is the maximum intensity pixel in an image

Tags: image, matlab, max

I have a tif file and I need to find the coordinates of the maximum intensity pixel. How would you solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is an image? grayscale? rgb? any other color space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the [max value and it's index](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) in the image with just `max`:

```
[maxVal,maxInd] = max(img(:));
```

If you are working with a RGB image, convert it to HSV and use the value component:

```
imgHSV = rgb2hsv(imgRGB);
img = imgHSV(:,:,3);
```

Also note that if there are multiple locations with the maximum value, `max` returns the index of the first occurrence.  To get all indexes with the maximum value,

```
allMaxValsMask = img==maxVal;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is:

```
% Find max value
maxValue = max(max(image));
% Find the pixel idx corresponding to that value
idx = find(image == maxValue);
```

If you have more than one value at `maxValue`, `idx` will be a vector containing all indexes at `maxValue`.

Also, the indexes in `idx` will be linear (not x,y coordinates). Depending on what you what, you might need to convert it back.